# Posting domain IP address into another file

Tags: python

Hello just a quick question people,
I want to get a domain's IP address and post it into another file example

```
>> import socket
>> socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
'216.58.203.100'
```

I want to take '216.58.203.100' and place it into a separate file like this:

```
add address=216.58.203.100 list=st
```

Is this possible ?
I'm only new to python and I'm not quite sure on what questions to ask.

-EDIT-

I understand appending a file put I'm just confused on how I take the the 'IP address' and place it in
`( add address= RIGHT HERE list=st )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate or how to use a function that returns a value or how to append to a file?

Comment: i want to take the value 'ipaddress' and place it in a file like so

    f = open("test/test.txt", "w+")
    f.write("theipaddress")

add address='tohere' list=st

    f.close()

Comment: Then you need to read a tutorial on functions and how they work, because it appears you already know how to write to a file and how to get the IP to print, but don't know how to do anything with it

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
f = open('ipfile.txt', 'w+')
f.write("add address={} list=st\n".format(ip))
f.close()
```